# How to use both Selenium and Scrapy?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I would like to scrape the title and the date but the bloomberg keep banning me so I used headless browser to scrape the item that I need

This is my code using selenium and scrapy

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class BloomergSpider(scrapy.Spider):    
name = 'bloomerg'
allowed_domains = ['www.bloomberg.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05- 
    30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker']

def parse(self, response):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05- 
   30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker')
    title = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
  "//div[text()='markets']//following:: 
 h1[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
    date = WebDriverWait(driver, 
 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
 "//div[text()='markets']//following:: h1[1]//following::div[@class='lede- 
text- 
v2__times']/time[@itemprop='datePublished']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
    driver.quit() 

    print(title)
    print(date)
```

I am having this kind of error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Please please help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your geckodriver to System Environment PATH, that's what is causing your error.

If you don't have one ( you should )
You can get the latest one from here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

If you're on Windows, search for 'Edit the System Environment Variables' and append the path to the geckodriver file to the PATH environment variable